# How to get req.body data using TypeScript, Express and Node with Routes in different files

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

I have been trying to answer this for days, searched through stackoverflow, the web and even rebuilt this multiple times.

I am trying to setup an express app using TypeScript to create a RESTApi, and I would like to keep my routes and controllers in separate files so I can have it organized.

I am open to other suggestions if this isn't the be best way.

The problem I am having is that if I output req.body it spits out the JSON that was sent but if I try to access `req.body['order_key'] or req.body.order_key` we get undefined

What am I doing wrong? :)

**index.ts**

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import express from 'express';
// import * as bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import orderRoutes from './routes/orderRoutes';
// import {getAllOrders, updateOrder} from './orderController';

const app = express();

app.use(express.json());
// app.use(bodyParser.json()); // tried
// app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // tried
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}));

app.use('/orders', orderRoutes);

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.status(200).send('Hey there!'));

// handle orders
// app.get('/orders', getAllOrders);
// app.post('/orders', updateOrder);

exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

I have tried to use bodyParser, the built in parser, all parser to get this to work

**orderRoutes.ts**

```
import {Router} from 'express';
import {getAllOrders, updateOrder} from '../controllers/orderController';
// eslint-disable-next-line new-cap
const router = Router();

router.route('/').post(updateOrder);
router.route('/').get(getAllOrders);

export default router;
```

**orderController.ts**

```
import {Request, Response} from 'express';

const getAllOrders = (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  res.status(200).send({
    status: 'success',
    message: 'Welcome',
  });
};

const updateOrder = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  res.status(200).send({
    status: 'success',
    message: 'Order created',
    data: 'data ' + req.body['order_key'] + req.body.order_key, // THIS IS THE ISSUE COMES UP UNDEFINED
  });
};

export {getAllOrders, updateOrder};
```

All the other routes work, here is the payload I am sending:

```
[
    {
        "id": 26442,
        "parent_id": 0,
        "customer_id": 1489,
        "order_key": "wc_order_DQSfOIyzobd4k"
    }
]
```

Using postman and I have it to RAW and with JSON on, screenshots below

Post issue

[Post issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7WS7d.png)

Headers

[Headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wvkOa.png)

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, your payload is an array with one object in it. As you show:

```
[
    {
        "id": 26442,
        "parent_id": 0,
        "customer_id": 1489,
        "order_key": "wc_order_DQSfOIyzobd4k"
    }
]
```

The brackets at the beginning and end indicate an array.  If you really intend for the payload to be an array, then you would need to use `req.body[0]` to access the first object in that array.

Or, `req.body[0].order_key` to get the key.

Or, if you want to process more than one object (if there is more than one in the array), then you would use a `for` loop to loop over the objects in the array.

---

Or, if the API is really just supposed to be sent one object, then fix the client-side so you're sending the JSON version of just a single object:

```
{
    "id": 26442,
    "parent_id": 0,
    "customer_id": 1489,
    "order_key": "wc_order_DQSfOIyzobd4k"
}
```

Comment: You know what is extremely frustrating? when you spend hours on something so simple, the reason I never even bothered to look at payload is this worked a few times then stopped, not sure even how the first few times worked! Thank you for the quick response I am rechecking and testing this now.

Comment: This was frustrating. The problem was in the frontend, and the backend was receiving `req.body.data` because of the arguments to axios as `{data}` instead of `{...data}`